# How do I access variables in this JSON return using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON data feed:

```
jQuery191029421305245357143_1380819227858(
    {
        "responseHeader": {
            "status": 0,
            "QTime": 127
        },
        "command": "build",
        "spellcheck": {
            "suggestions": [
                "restaurant",
                {
                    "numFound": 1,
                    "startOffset": 0,
                    "endOffset": 10,
                    "suggestion": [
                        "restaurants"
                    ]
                },
                "berl",
                {
                    "numFound": 4,
                    "startOffset": 11,
                    "endOffset": 15,
                    "suggestion": [
                        "berlin",
                        "berlin brandenburg",
                        "berlin hamburg",
                        "berliner"
                    ]
                },
                "collation",
                "restaurant berlin",
                "collation",
                "restaurant (berlin brandenburg)",
                "collation",
                "restaurants berlin",
                "collation",
                "restaurant (berlin hamburg)"
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

and i try to access the following data in JQuery:

```
"restaurant berlin"
"restaurant (berlin brandenburg)"
"restaurants berlin"
"restaurant (berlin hamburg)"
```

I have the following JQUERY code so far:

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map(data.spellcheck.suggestions, function(item) {    
        return item;
}));
```

which is working but return me all values and not only the 4 data sets outlined above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your "json" looks incorrectly formatted... why do you have an array that is a mixture of objects and strings? wouldn't it be better to make it consistent by making all of them objects?

Comment: This is *jsonp*, right ?

Comment: @KevinB The json is not incorrect, I wouldn't say I'd do it like that if I could choose, but this is valid JSON, you can mix and match whatever you want inside an array.

Comment: i didn't say it was invalid or incorrect, it's just... not normal. it can be done using the current format, but using a more consistent format would make it much easier to work with, otherwise on each iteration you have to detect whether it's a string or an object and handle it differently for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback for the jQuery `map`-function you can do a check and return null if you do not want the item in the result.

The following snippet shows an example of how to filter out everything that's not a string and everything that's a string equal to "collation":

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map(data.spellcheck.suggestions, function(item) {    
        if (typeof item != "string") return;
        if (item === "collation") return;
        return item;
}));
```

Comment: thank you!. this is what I was looking for. There is 1 last small issue: How can I remove the results "restaurant" and "berl" from the result?

Comment: You'd have to do some string conversion/parsing to return the correct values. In essence, the callback receives every item from the collection and creates a new collection with what you return from each call.

Comment: Could you first try something? This is basic programming.